# Quantum (higher-form) anomaly at finite temperature

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, topological-order, quantum-anomalies, topological-phase

At finite temperature, anomaly is generally known to be contaminated, and thus the 't Hooft anomaly matching does not work after thermal compactification. Meanwhile, I have read paper saying that anomaly from higher-form symmetry can remains robust even at finite temperature, e.g.,

1. "[Circle compactification and ’t Hooft anomaly](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.08923)" , by Yuya Tanizaki, Tatsuhiro Misumi, Norisuke Sakaic;
2. "[Theta, Time Reversal, and Temperature](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.00501)", by Davide Gaiotto, Anton Kapustin, Zohar Komargodski, and Nathan Seiberg.

However, I do not understand their derivations, can any one help to comment/explain on this?